# Impala add column with default value

Tags: cloudera, impala, hue

I want to add a column to an existing impala table(and view) with a default value (so that the existing rows also have a value). The column should not allow null values.

```
ALTER TABLE dbName.tblName ADD COLUMNS (id STRING NOT NULL '-1')
```

I went through the docs but could not find an example that specifically does this. How do I do this in Impala? Hue underlines/does not recognize the NOT NULL command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Kudu as a storage layer for your table? Because if not, then according to [Impala docs](http://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_kudu.html),

> **Note:** Impala only allows PRIMARY KEY clauses and NOT NULL constraints on
> columns for Kudu tables. These constraints are enforced on the Kudu
> side.
>
> ...
>
> For non-Kudu tables, Impala allows any column to contain NULL values,
> because it is not practical to enforce a "not null" constraint on HDFS
> data files that could be prepared using external tools and ETL
> processes.

Impala's [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_alter_table.html#alter_table) syntax also does not support specifying default column values (in general, non-Kudu).

Comment: Not t using Kudu. Can I then insert a value for the column, after I add the column in Impala table? Like make the entire column to have a particular value

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` over non-Kudu storage only updates table metadata not affecting the underlying data. So unfortunately, I don't think what you want is possible unless you rewrite the whole table.

Comment: I was wondering if you or anyone has suggestions on how to deal with existing rows when a new column is added in the Impala table. I don't want that column to have a null value.

Comment: Hi @user2441441, How are you feeding the table?

Comment: If you don't feel like rewriting the table, **as a temporary measure,** maybe `CREATE VIEW` on top of it and use `IFNULL(id,'-1') id` in it.

Answer (score 1):

With `Impala` you could try as follow

add the column

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbName.tblName ADD COLUMNS(id STRING);
```

once you've added the column you can fill that column as below using the same table

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE dbName.tblName SELECT col1,...,coln, '-1' FROM dbName.tblName;
```

where col1,...,coln are the previous columns before the `add columns` command and `'-1'` is to fill the new column.